# custom field value is blank

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

```
function add_custom_fields($post_id) {
            global $post;
        
        $metadescription = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55 );
        
        add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_description', $metadescription, true );
        
          }
    
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'add_custom_fields' );
```

what i going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include expected behavior, and what is the issue. Make sure to include any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code that will add_post_meta every time a post or page is created or updated on your website.

```
function add_custom_fields($post_id) {

    // If this is a revision, don't add content.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

    global $post;
    $metadescription = wp_trim_words( apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content), 55, '');
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_description',$metadescription, true);
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'add_custom_fields', 10, 1 );
```